# Worker getting null when retrieving shared property

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, worker

For some reason, when I try to receive a shared property from a `Worker` (in AS3), the result is always null. That is, I send a value to a `Worker` using `setSharedProperty()`, when I retrieve it using `getSharedProperty()`, it always returns `undefined`/`null`.

Here's a simple test I set up:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.system.Worker;
    import flash.system.WorkerDomain;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var _worker:Worker;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (Worker.current.isPrimordial)
            {
                initMain();
            }
            else
            {
                initWorker();
            }
        }

        private function initMain():void 
        {
            _worker = WorkerDomain.current.createWorker(this.loaderInfo.bytes);

            _worker.setSharedProperty("message", "test");
            _worker.start();
        }

        private function initWorker():void 
        {
            _worker = Worker.current;

            var message:String = _worker.getSharedProperty("message");

            trace(message);
        }

    }

}
```

When I trace `message`, the result is null. Although my main goal is to make an AIR app, I get the same result whether I'm compiling for AIR (3.7) or Flash Player (11.6, for some reason 11.7 doesn't recognise flash.system.Worker as a valid class).

I'm compiling using the Flex SDK, through FlashDevelop. Does anybody know what's wrong, maybe I've missed something in my code?

Comment: I don't have an answer to your main problem, but the problem with Flash 11.7 not recognizing classes might be due to your playerglobal.SWC or the SWF version that is being compiled. The current SWF version seems to be 19, you might need to specify one that includes the `Worker` functionality.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that. After updating FlashDevelop (which also updates the Flex and AIR SDKs), it now compiles for 11.7. The main problem persists, though.

Comment: Add `trace(_worker.getSharedProperty("message"))` right after `_worker.setSharedProperty("message", "test")`. Do you get the property then? If not, there is no need to even discuss the function `initWorker`, as we can determine the problem starts before then.

Comment: That does work. I did a bit of experimentation though, and I think I've concluded that this only happens when testing it in debug mode. When running in release mode, it successfully reads the property from within the worker (I tested this without traces, using if statements and drawing to the stage). It is a real bummer though, since I trace a lot to debug my code. Still, should this question be considered solved?

Comment: Seems to be an issue with FD. http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=9870

Comment: I compiled your code form the commandline and it worked as-is, in debug mode.  Command is as follows (note I run linux, so I use wine to run a newer Flash Player standalone debugger):  `$AIR_HOME/bin/mxmlc -swf-version=18 Main.as -debug && wine /home/admin/Downloads/flashplayer_11_sa_debug.exe Main.swf`.  I tried the flash standalone player and the ADL AIR simulator, and in both cases the trace log successfully says `test`.  Perhaps you could try a command-line build.  You should also probably check `Worker.isSupported` in the code.  Perhaps you're running on a single-core machine?

Comment: Oh, and there's a big difference between tracing null and getting no trace statement.  You should add some more trace statements throughout (i.e. main worker started, Worker.isSupported=..., secondary worker started, setting shared value, got shared value: ..., etc)

Comment: Glad to hear you had more success! Ironic that using debug mode would be the cause of a bug, when it is intended to prevent them!

Comment: OK well, first of all I'm sure Workers are supported, I have a dual-core machine and they do work in release mode. I'm not sure why this isn't working in debug mode, but I've found a workaround for tracing (writing to a log file). As The_asMan said it might be an issue with FD, but in my case the worker is running, just not receiving the shared property correctly. I could do what Jeff suggested, but to be honest building from the command line seems like more trouble than it's worth. I might give it a shot though, just to see if it works at all.

Comment: The only reason I'd suggest building from the command-line is to see if it works.  Then you narrow it down to something FD is doing in its build/simulate process - you start whittling away build options until you find what breaks it.  It's actually pretty easy to build from the command-line, here's the [batch file](http://onetacoshort.com/temp/simulate.bat) and [application xml](http://onetacoshort.com/temp/simulate.xml) - save them in the directory with your Main.as, change the .bat `C:\air_sdk_3.6` to the location of your AIR SDK.  Then open cmd, cd to your folder, and run `simulate`.

Comment: Huh. I tried that, and I do indeed get `test` in the trace log. So there's something that FD is screwing up, but I don't know what it could be. This might be worth reporting on the FD forums, and perhaps they can fix it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FlashDevelop now seems to have complete support for debugging workers which really wasn't the case on older versions (you could neither break, or trace inside workers). AIR SDK workers support has also progressed (I remember things working in release would break in debug version)
I just recompiled your sample with AIR SDK 14 release (14.0.0.110)

```
air14_sdk_win/bin/mxmlc -swf-version=25 -debug=true Main.as
```

and debugged it with Shockwave Flash Debugger 14,0,0,125 and FlashDevelop 4.6.1.30 and got the expected result:

```
[Starting debug session with FDB]
Created Worker 2
test
```

Beware that any element not up-to-date in your debugging chain (sdk/player/debugger) could result in problems for debugging workers

Comment: Ah, that's good to know! I'm currently not using Flash much anymore, but I appreciate your answer all the same! Since there's nothing better to do I suppose I'll mark this to show that the problem is solved, even if this doesn't technically answer the question (it's simply notifying me of a fix).